# The program compiles successfully when i store the address returned by malloc in Integer variable

Tags: c, malloc, type-conversion

Consider the below code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    return 0;
}
```

The above program [compiles successfully](https://ideone.com/Dwagl) without any warning.

Shouldn't it give error/warning as address of memory chunk is being stored in `integer variable` rather than a pointer?

Initially, i believed that the behavior is strange because i forgot to include `stdlib`.
Soon, my assumption failed. The behavior is same even after including `stdlib`.

See the below program after including `stdlib`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    return 0;
}
```

This program has also the [similar behavior.](https://ideone.com/a3oB5)

Why it compiles successfully?

Comment: This depends on the compiler.  You should try compiling with -Wall.

Comment: Enable all warnings and errors before you post here. With GCC, say at least `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Where is the option to enable warnings on ideone?

Comment: @Aashish, Try http://liveworkspace.org/. It's more up to date and has some good options turned on. It even has boost.

Comment: Also you didn't include stdlib so you have managed to create the infamous malloc bug. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compiles succesfully but you should receive a warning :

```
> gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:13: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

You should never discard compiler warnings. I used gcc 4.7 without any options.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` is returning a `void *` type. What you're returning and storing in to that int is the address of the `void *`. This is a perfectly legal thing to do, if for example you wanted to printf the address of the malloc'ed memory before using it you could:

```
int main()
{
    int *r = NULL;
    int p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    printf("%#x\n",p);
    r = (int *)p; 
    *r = 5;
    printf("%d\n", *r);
    free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't really make a lot of sense... but there's a reason for not getting an error when using this code. As far as a warning goes... you should have gotten one.

VS gives:

```
1>c:\users\ma\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.c(7): warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
```